# Pivot table where columns have a multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I can't seem to figure out how to pivot a data frame with columns with a multilevel index.

I have seen this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812409/pivot-table-with-multilevel-columns), but can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my problem.

If I Have `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('Mule Creek', 'ATI'): {5: 5.0, 6: 6.0, 7: 7.0, 8: 8.0, 9: 9.0},
 ('Mule Creek', 'ATIMR'): {5: 0.04115419564079352,
  6: 0.04115419564079352,
  7: 0.04115419564079352,
  8: 0.04115419564079352,
  9: 0.04115419564079352},
 ('Saddle Mtn.', 'ATI'): {5: 5.0, 6: 6.0, 7: 7.0, 8: 8.0, 9: 9.0},
 ('Saddle Mtn.', 'ATIMR'): {5: 0.05260285024705004,
  6: 0.05260285024705004,
  7: 0.05260285024705004,
  8: 0.05260285024705004,
  9: 0.05260285024705004},
 ('Calvert Creek', 'ATI'): {5: 5.0, 6: 6.0, 7: 7.0, 8: 8.0, 9: 9.0},
 ('Calvert Creek', 'ATIMR'): {5: 0.0068488368752893354,
  6: 0.0068488368752893354,
  7: 0.0068488368752893354,
  8: 0.0068488368752893354,
  9: 0.0068488368752893354}})
```

I want to create a pivot table where `ATI` becomes the index and use `aggfunc='mean'.

I have tried:

```
df= df.unstack(level=-1)
df =df.pivot_table(values=tmp[0],index='level_0',columns='level_1',aggfunc=np.mean)
```

But I get:

```
KeyError: 1.0
```

Desired result:

```
         ATI  ATIMR
5        5.0  0.0335353
6        6.0  0.0335353
7        7.0  0.0335353
8        8.0  0.0335353
9        9.0  0.0335353
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
newdf=df.stack(level=0).mean(level=0)
newdf
Out[886]: 
   ATI     ATIMR
5  5.0  0.033535
6  6.0  0.033535
7  7.0  0.033535
8  8.0  0.033535
9  9.0  0.033535
```

Comment: exactly what I needed!